# Laravel frequently showing 'Undefined variable: _SERVER'

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

I am frequently getting the following error in Laravel 5.4.

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SERVER in
>   C:\wamp64\www\hxponline\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php on
>   line 305
>        Notice: Undefined variable: _GET in C:\wamp64\www\hxponline\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php on
>   line 315
>        Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createRequestFromFactory()
>   must be of the type array, null given, called in
>   C:\wamp64\www\hxponline\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php on
>   line 315 and defined in
>   C:\wamp64\www\hxponline\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php:2014
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\wamp64\www\hxponline\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php(315):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createRequestFromFactory(NULL,
>   Array, Array, Array, Array, NULL) #1
>   C:\wamp64\www\hxponline\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Request.php(59):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals() #2
>   C:\wamp64\www\hxponline\public\index.php(53):
>   Illuminate\Http\Request::capture() #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\wamp64\www\hxponline\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php on
>   line 2014

Also in the phpmyadmin page I am getting,

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setCookie() on
>   null in C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.7.4\libraries\ThemeManager.php:260
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.7.4\libraries\common.inc.php(616):
>   PMA\libraries\ThemeManager->setThemeCookie() #1
>   C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.7.4\sql.php(18):
>   require_once('C:\wamp64\apps\...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.7.4\libraries\ThemeManager.php on line 260

I couldn't figure out any reason what is the reason for all these errors.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you might have been playing about in either `php.ini` or `httpd.conf`. What version of WAMPServer are you running? And what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: running latest version of wamp server Version 3.1.0 - 64bit and php 7.0 or greater

Comment: What are the values on `variables_order` in your `php.ini`

Comment: Its variables_order = "GPCS"

Comment: Ok that looks good, so its not that

Comment: is that any problem with laravel configuration??

Comment: i have to restart the wamp all the time in order to avoid the error..but its not a proper solution i have to fix it permanently..

Comment: Have you actually selected a PHP version > 7.0 or are you using the 5.6 version that comes with that WAMPServer as well

Comment: not using php 5.6 , actually running in php version >7.0

Comment: Has this issue been resolved by someone??? I am thinking about installing xamp if this problem is related to wamp.